# Поиск повторяющихся текстовых последовательностей в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Есть текст:

```
PROMPT
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LINESIZE 255
SET PAGESIZE 1000

PROMPT
PROMPT Constraints Owned By Table
PROMPT ==========================
SELECT c.constraint_name "Constraint",
Decode(c.constraint_type,'P','Primary Key',
'U','Unique Key',
'C','Check',
'R','Foreign Key',
c.constraint_type) "Type",
c.r_owner "Ref Table",
c.r_constraint_name "Ref Constraint"
FROM all_constraints c
WHERE c.table_name = Upper('&&1')
AND c.owner = Upper('&&2');


PROMPT
PROMPT Constraints Referencing Table
PROMPT =============================
SELECT c1.table_name "Table",
c1.constraint_name "Foreign Key",
c1.r_constraint_name "References"
FROM all_constraints c1
WHERE c1.owner = Upper('&&2')
AND c1.r_constraint_name IN (SELECT c2.constraint_name
FROM all_constraints c2
WHERE c2.table_name = Upper('&&1')
AND c2.owner = Upper('&&2')
AND c2.constraint_type IN ('P','U'));

SET VERIFY ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET PAGESIZE 1000
PROMPT
```

Я хочу найти все выражения "SELECT...;" , используя Python3 и регулярные выражения re.* .

Выражение (SELECT.*;) слишком жадное и возвращает все от первого "SELECT" до последнего ";"

Comment: На вскидку `.*?` менее жадно и должно помочь.

Comment: Боюсь что регулярками это не решается. Возможно split по `;` вам поможет.

Comment: Дело в том, что в строковых константах, в комментариях и в некоторых других частях запроса может присутствовать ', при этом `'` может быть как открывающимся/закрывающимся, так и служебным апострофом, или самостоятельным апострофом (коментарий). Различить  `;` находится в коментарии или строковой константе - не вижу возможности.

Comment: Спасибо Mike, работает :)

Answer (score 1):

`.+?` нежадная версия с `?` заработала:

```py
re.findall("(SELECT.+?);+", response.text,
           re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
```